# iFrame says "Refused to frame 'xx.xx' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://xx.xx"."

Tags: iframe, android-management-api

I'm trying to connect to play.google.com in my website iframe and I'm receiving this error:

Refused to frame 'https://play.google.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://play.google.com".

Am I missing some thing??

Here is the code:
[image: code]

Here is the error:
[image: Output]

Can I do something so that I can work?

The code reference which I took from google is [here](https://developers.google.com/android/management/managed-configurations-iframe#render_the_iframe).

I was trying to render the iframe after using Android Management API. What I was expecting is when I open the url directly in new tab then it's working but when  I try to open in iframe it's not working. It should work in iframe!

Comment: Can anybody post answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can occur when you render the [Managed Configurations iframe](https://developers.google.com/android/management/managed-configurations-iframe#add_the_iframe_to_your_console) over an ‘http’ (unsecure) connection. I suggest you embed your iframe with an ‘https’ (secure) connection to prevent cross-site scripting attacks. I tested this locally, and swapping to ‘https’ resolved the issue in my tests.

Comment: It render with https only.. still same problem